# Modify memory without patching the database

Tags: ida, idapython

Is there a way to modify one or more bytes in memory without making any changes in the database? I know about idc.PatchByte() in idapython, but it will print the message that states that 'This database has been patched' on the next run.

Comment: You may also try **Edit -> Patch program -> Change byte/word** in IDA Pro.

PS: Consider to save the state of your IDA Database before changing bytes with *Database snapshot manager(Ctrl+Shift+T)*. It will help you to avoid troubles if something will go wrong.

If you want to patch the binary that you dissect, there are a plenty of ways to do that. You may use **Edit -> Patch program -> Apply patches to input file** in IDA Pro. Alternatively you may modify a binary in a debugger or with some hex editor. What would you like to modify?

Comment: This is not suitable for me for exactly the same reason why idc.PatchByte() is not suitable for me. I estimated that the first answer will be like that - sorry that I hadn't mentioned this in op post.

Comment: Probably PatchDbgByte(ea,value) from IDA Pro command line or in script will help. As descibed in idc.py this function meant to "Change a byte in the debugged process memory only".

Answer (score 1):

You can do it even in free IDA.
Setup a breakpoint and use its `condition` property in  Edit BreakPoint.
This way you can change registers, memory, and even perform more complex actions.
For example:

```
patch_dbg_byte(rcx+2,0),0
```

Byte at address `rcx+2` is cleared when the breakpoint is hit.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I'm answering my own question:

```
DbgWrite(ea, data)
    Write to debugger memory.
    
    @param ea: linear address
    @param data: string to write
    @return: number of written bytes (-1 - network/debugger error)
    
    Thread-safe function (may be called only from the main thread and debthread)
```